# display+touch and network+ do not open on lumia 520

Tags: 8.0, settings, system-apps

In settings, display+touch and network+ are not opening on my Lumia 520.

I bought this phone from showroom with Update 2. 
It has "OS version: 8.0.10327.77 or 8.0.10328.78".

Comment: When you say "bought from showroom", do you mean from a carrier? If so which one?

Comment: have you tried resetting the phone?

Answer (score -1):

Simply update [display+touch](http://www.wpcentral.com/nokia-updates-display-touch-lumia-phones-details-are-lacking) and also [network+](http://www.wpcentral.com/nokia-pushes-out-another-network-update-lumias) apps. Then everything will work fine.

On the site you and scan the barcode and your phone will navigate to the update.